# Prove the linear independence of these two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Assume **u** and **v** are independent vectors. Using the definition of linear independence, I need should that the vectors **a = 4u + 5v** and **b = 6u - 2v** are also linearly independent. I know that I need to show that 2 constants **p** and **q** must be equal to 0 in the equation **pa + qb = 0**, but how is that done using the independence of **u** and **v**? What is it about **u** and **v** that stops **a** and **b** from being scalar multiples of each other?

Comment: $pa + qb = p(4u + 5v) + q(6u-2v) = (4p + 6q)u + (5p - 2q)v$. Now as $u$ and $v$ are linearly indep, what can you say if $pa + qb = 0$?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $p\mathbf a+q\mathbf b=\mathbf 0$. Then $(4p+6q)\mathbf u+(5p-2q)\mathbf v=\mathbf 0$, hence $4p+6q=0$ and $5p-2q=0$. You can conclude from this that $p=q=0$. For example, $19p=(4p+6q)+3\cdot(5p-2q)=0$.